# Was Jesus made to be SIN or a SIN OFFERING?

Tags: textual-criticism, 2-corinthians, sin

> the righteousness of
> God in him. 2nd Corinthians 5:21 (KJV)

I have not found a sufficient examination on this site for the true interpretation of this verse. I read my Russian bible primarily and it says this:

> Ибо не знавшего греха Он сделал для нас [жертвою за] грех, чтобы мы в Нем сделались праведными пред
> Богом. 2-е Коринфянам 5:21 (Russian Synodal Version)

Here it states in brackets, that is added for context and further meaning, that Jesus was a "sin offering". I don't know Greek, but the word ἁμαρτίαν (hamartia G266) seems to mean "committing an offence". From what I understand, the Russian Synodal Version and KJV both used Textus Receptus. Theologically I agree with "sin offering" and always have. I am disappointed in the way that the English and western translations have translated it.

The latter part of the verse also differs but that can be made into a different question entirely ("made the righteousness of God in Him" vs. "in Him made righteous before God").

Which one translation is correct?

Comment: ( https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13901/what-is-the-correct-translation-of-ἁμαρτίαν-in-2-corinthians-521-what-did-god )